# Can't install visual studio 2010 rc on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've downloaded the iso, mounted, and installer is running fine. However gets stuck during loading setup components. Just sits there and nothing happens.

What can I do to fix this, if anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this exact same install a week or so ago. On a pretty nippy system with a recent clean Win7 install, the VS2010RC took a good half-an-hour to do it's stuff. Patience, young padowan. :)

Answer (score 0):

wait longer - it takes ages to load the setup components....